# How do I solve an ODE Two-Point Boundary Value Problem?

Tags: ode, boundary-conditions

I have a feeling my question is a very basic one, but I am not at all well versed in computational sciences.

My equations are of the form:

$$
y \in \mathbb{R}^3 \\
\dot{y}(t) = f(y(t)) \\
y_1(0) = a \\
y_2(T) = b \\
y_3(T) = c \\
$$

Is there a known method to numerically solve such a set of equations?

Comment: Is there a particular software package or language you're looking to solve this problem in? For someone not well versed in computational sciences, it might help with software recommendations.

Comment: Any introductory text on numerical methods will have a chapter on this topic.

Comment: What are $y_1$, $y_2$ and $y_3$ and how do they relate to $y(t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this problem using a [multiple shooting method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_multiple_shooting_method); you need only find initial conditions $y_{2}(0)$ and $y_{3}(0)$ that yield a solution consistent with your stated "final conditions". These values are typically called "boundary values"; your problem is called a two-point boundary value problem. It is worth noting that multiple shooting methods are more numerically stable than single shooting methods.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for correcting my amateur wording of the question.

Comment: No worries! I've had similar troubles getting up to speed in new fields. Sometimes, you just need a result to get a paper done, not a thorough grounding in a subject. As computational scientists, we should be helping people out with questions like yours, and I want to be a good ambassador for the community, because positive experiences are how we get people involved.